# anyone tried new php beta release with anonymous functions?

Tags: php, programming-languages, lambda, functional-programming

has anybody tried out the new 5.3.0 RC1 php release and played a bit with anonymous functions?

I would like to know if you can use it like python for functional programming.

E.g., can you do something like:

```
def sinus(x):
  if x<=0.1:
    return x
  else:
    return (lambda x: 3*x-4*x*x*x)(sinus(x/3))

print sinus(172.0)
```

Or better, can you do all the cool stuff like in python or lisp?
Are there any limits?
Unfortunately I don´t have a better example in mind. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new anonymous functions in PHP 5.3 are very useful in existing callback functions. As this example shows.

```
echo preg_replace_callback('~-([a-z])~', function ($match) {
    return strtoupper($match[1]);
}, 'hello-world');
// outputs helloWorld
```

It's still a trick, since PHP 5.3 impliments a Closure class that makes a class instance invokable.

[Wikipedia quote:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#5.3)

> PHP 5.3 mimics anonymous functions but it does not support true anonymous functions because PHP functions are still not first-class functions.

You can read more about the Closures in this [PHP RFC](http://wiki.php.net/rfc/closures)

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP 4 you can use the function [create_function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) to do what you want.

In your example:

```
<?php

function sinus($x){
  if($x < 0.1) {
    return $x;
  } else {
    $func = create_function('$x', 'return 3*$x-4*$x*$x*$x');
    return $func( sinus($x/3) );
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: oh really, never looked at that. I thought that you can`t programm in a functional way in php. And just see anonym functions in the release notes :) So the new feature is only another way to define anonym functions?

Comment: create_function() is similiar to eval() isn't it ? The new way described by Ólafur Waage looks much better.

Comment: eval() lets you "run" any piece of PHP code (i.e.eval("print (1 + 9);"), whereas create_function() creates a function and returns it to be used later, as the example I wrote above.